# Sitecore > Default Storefront(pbCS) installation > Product detail page returns a Null Refference Exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, storefront, commerceserver

I was trying to install the [default Storefront site](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS81/SCpbCSRefSfGuide/en-us/index.html#GettingStarted.html)(powered by Commerce Server). It looks good at the moment, I managed to rebuild all indexes and publish the content. However, I can't reach product detail page - I receive an exception.
Example [here](http://screencast.com/t/MKtlkUTy1pe7).

I had faced with the similar issue when I tried to click on any catalog category.
The log-file contains the same error message without any details. Could you please suggest something to fix this issue?

P.S. After the finishing the installation I didn't have any products on the site. I fixed that issue:

1. selected the default Adventure Works catalog in the Sitecore tree([using content manager](http://screencast.com/t/3IJjiugQjcR)).
2. Filled in field [CategoryDatasource](http://screencast.com/t/LbAF2vDY)(with the path to categories)

I think it might cause the error which I described above.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: When you open Sitecore, do you have products? See this image. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bjvgrcmfztvauv/Sitecore%20Commerce%201.png?dl=0

Comment: I have it working here. Hopefully I can help. http://commerce81.codewolf.io/shop/Boots_boots/Sierras_aw087-04

Comment: Can you compare my App Config files to yours, maybe you missed something in the merge. Use Beyond Compare or what ever diff tool you like. https://www.dropbox.com/s/stc40uq67452cxa/App_Config2.rar?dl=0

Comment: Lastly, is the adventureworks catalog selected for your home node? https://www.dropbox.com/s/dcjxrkwltmttn8w/Catalog%20Settings.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help. Your last suggestion(about home node) was correct!!! Please add it as an answer I will mark it  as a correct one!

Comment: Thank you. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the catalog for the site via a home node property.

[image]